# Ajax call not hitting the webmethod in C# Code Behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Good morning. 
Currently I'm having a problem having my ajax call go from the JQuery to C# code behind.  After that's successful it should return the true value at the end of the function.  I've tried removing the type and changing the web method to an HttpPost header which I can't do. Here's an example of the code.

Javascript

```
var jsonFormValues = JSON.stringify(formValues);
    $.ajax({
        type:POST,
        async: false,
        url: "RegistryOpt.aspx/SendOpt",
        data: { jsonFormValues: jsonFormValues },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            onWebMethodSucceeded();
        }
    });
```

C#

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static bool SendOpt(string jsonFormValues)
{
    Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonFormValues));

    var fv = Json.Decode<FormValues>(jsonFormValues);

    fv.attestationItems = RegistryOpt.FormatAttestation(fv.attestation);

    var eb = new EmailBuilder(fv);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the error?  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  Is the HTTP request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: And why is your C# method static ? Aren't you in a Controller or something like that ?

Comment: @David I don't see any errors in the console / browser.

Comment: @Miiite No, it's not a controller. It's just a regular ASPX page.

Comment: @MasterP: And... Is the HTTP request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: I haven't done ASPX in a long while, but I don't remember the methods in ASPX code beding to be static

Comment: @Miiite I've made the method static and non static.  It doesn't hit the break point I have set inside the function unfortunately.

Comment: Side note: `async: false` is a famously bad idea.  (And I'm genuinely surprised there's *nothing* on the browser console warning you about it.)  This behavior is very much an anti-battern and is actively being deprecated by browsers.  Keep your asynchronous code asynchronous.

Comment: Hi, Remove the c# web method to "(EnableSession = true)" and then try once.

Comment: Have you tried  `data:JSON.stringify({ jsonFormValues: jsonFormValues })`

Comment: @Miiite *Page Method*s must be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are formatting to JSON only parameter value. Instead of `var jsonFormValues = JSON.stringify(formValues);`, you need to use `JSON.stringify` for parameter itself too:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:POST,
        async: false,
        url: "RegistryOpt.aspx/SendOpt",
        data: JSON.stringify({ jsonFormValues: formValues }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            onWebMethodSucceeded();
        }
    });
```